# iterate through a repeated tag in xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml element like this:

```
<book>
    <English color="blue" author="hasan" />
    <English color="red" author="david" />
</book>
```

Is it possible to iterate through it using xslt and produce the output like the one below ?

```
<book>
    <English color="yellow" author="hally" />
    <English color="pink" author="gufoo" />
</book>
```

here is the one i am trying;

```
<xsl:template match = /book> 
  <xsl:for-each select "./English"> 
    <xsl:if test="@color = '"yellow"'"> 
    <English color="yellow"/> 
    <xsl:if test="@color = '"red"'"> 
    <English color="pink"/> 
  </xsl:for-each> 
 </xsl-template>
```

Comment: Other than the values of the attributes, is there supposed to be a difference here?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, those two files share only structure, the data is completely different.  What are the rules that control the transformation?  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for posting guidelines.

Comment: Sorry if my expressing method was not correct. what i need is , if the attribute "color" is blue, it should be replaced by yellow, if the color is red , it should be replaced by pink.

Comment: The answer is yes. It's possible.

Comment: @tom. I am not familiar with xslt ,  am looking through some tutorials, can u explain the same?

Comment: @parameswar show us what you've tried and we'll improve on it.

Comment: sorry if i seem foolish,here is the one i am trying;             <xsl:template match  = /book>
<xsl:for-each select "./English">
 <xsl:if test="@color = '"yellow"'">
 <English color="yellow"/>
 <xsl:if test="@color = '"red"'">
 <English color="pink"/> 
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl-template>

Comment: @parameswar your syntax is wrong. You have to close the xsl:if tags after creating the English element.

Comment: but how do i create english tag, if dont have the new values?

Comment: in the one i am trying,the first if condition is blue, sorry for the typos

Comment: @parameswar when you write <English /> , you create an element. It's basically the same as using an element constructor like this <xsl:element name="English />

Answer (score 0):

Try the following stylesheet. I got rid of the xsl:for-each element cause I think it's more simple to do it this way. Also, using foreach loops in a declarative language like XSL doesn't seem right to me. I prefer to leave those for imperative languages.

There are many different ways you could achieve a result like this. You should take a while to try modifying this and experiment a bit. 
As an exercise, you could remove the if statements and try to achieve a similar result using templates and predicates. You'll probably have to read some tutorials on XSL before you do so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Copy every element or attribute encountered 
       and find matching templates for its attributes
       and child elements 
   -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- For every attribute named "color" that has a value of red or blue, 
  follow the conditions defined in if blocks.
  Notice that the specified color attributes will not be copied according
  to the template above as the one selected is always the last
  matching one in your XSL.
  This way both the "author" attributes and "color" attributes with values
  different than red and blue will be matched by the other template.
  The dot "." means the currently processed node (usually element or attribute) 
  -->
  <xsl:template match="@color[. = 'blue' or . = 'red']">
   <xsl:attribute name="color">
     <xsl:if test=". = 'blue'">yellow</xsl:if>
     <xsl:if test=". = 'red'">pink</xsl:if>
   </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You should replace those first 2 templates with the identity transform (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying)

Comment: @DevNull true. I wanted to do it in a different way but I changed my mind halfway through. I admit it ended up a bit messy.